# Extract nested JSON in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to unpack nested JSON in the following pandas dataframe:

```
           id                                                              info
0           0  [{u'a': u'good', u'b': u'type1'}, {u'a': u'bad', u'b': u'type2'}]
1           1  [{u'a': u'bad', u'b': u'type1'}, {u'a': u'bad', u'b': u'type2'}]
2           2  [{u'a': u'good', u'b': u'type1'}, {u'a': u'good', u'b': u'type2'}]
```

My expected outcome is:

```
           id        type1    type2
0           0        good     bad
1           1        bad      bad
2           2        good     good
```

I've been looking at other solutions including `json_normalize` but it does not work for me unfortunately. Should I treat the JSON as a string to get what I want? Or is there a more straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Use `json_normalize` to handle a `list` of dictionaries and break individual dicts into separate series after setting the common path, which is *info* here. Then, `unstack` + apply series which gets appended downwards for that level.

---

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df_info = json_normalize(df.to_dict('list'), ['info']).unstack().apply(pd.Series)
df_info
```

[image]

2. Pivot the `DF` with an optional `aggfunc` to handle duplicated index axis:

---

```
DF = df_info.pivot_table(index=df_info.index.get_level_values(1), columns=['b'], 
                         values=['a'], aggfunc=' '.join)

DF
```

[image]

3. Finally Concatenate sideways:

---

```
pd.concat([df[['ID']], DF.xs('a', axis=1).rename_axis(None, 1)], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

Starting `DF` used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=[0,1,2], info=[[{u'a': u'good', u'b': u'type1'}, {u'a': u'bad', u'b': u'type2'}], 
                                        [{u'a': u'bad', u'b': u'type1'}, {u'a': u'bad', u'b': u'type2'}],
                                        [{u'a': u'good', u'b': u'type1'}, {u'a': u'good', u'b': u'type2'}]]))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just had to change the rows type from `str`to `list` first. Nice little hack. Many Thanks!